# having trouble writing dictionary list as a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that creates an address book with contact names, emails, phone numbers, etc. I store each contact as a dictionary and then place each person (dictionary) into a global list. I then convert the list to a string using `repr()` and write it to a file. When I try to reload the list and write what it contains, I get a list of empty dictionaries. Please help me figure out what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
list = []
listfile = 'phonebook.txt'

class bookEntry(dict):
    total = 0

    def __init__(self):
        bookEntry.total += 1
        self.d = {}

    def __del__(self):
        bookEntry.total -= 1

class Person(bookEntry):
    def __init__(self, n):
        bookEntry.__init__(self)
        self.n = n
        print '%s has been created' % (self.n)

    def addnewperson(self, n, e = '', ph = '', note = ''):
        f = file(listfile, 'w')

        self.d['name'] = n
        self.d['email'] = e
        self.d['phone'] = ph
        self.d['note'] = note

        list.append(self)
        listStr = repr(list)
        f.write(listStr)

        f.close()
```

I start the program with a `startup()` function:

```
def startup():
    aor = raw_input('Hello! Would you like to add an entry or retrieve one?')
    if aor == 'add':
        info = raw_input('Would you like to add a person or a company?')
        if info == 'person':
            n = raw_input('Please enter this persons name:')
            e = raw_input('Please enter this persons email address:')
            ph = raw_input('Please enter this persons phone number:')
            note = raw_input('Please add any notes if applicable:')

            X = Person(n)
            X.addnewperson(n, e, ph, note)
startup()
```

I add these answers to the prompts:

```
'''
    Hello! Would you like to add an entry or retrieve one?add
    Would you like to add a person or a company?person
    Please enter this persons name:Pig
    Please enter this persons email address:pig@brickhouse.com
    Please enter this persons phone number:333-333-3333
    Please add any notes if applicable:one of three
    Pig has been created
'''
```

When I open `phonebook.txt`, this is what I see:

```
[{}]
```

Why are empty dictionaries being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deriving from `dict`, but storing all the elements in a member `d`. Hence, `repr` gives you a string representing an empty `dict`. If you want to use a `bookEntry` as a `dict`, insert the info with

```
self['name'] = n
```

instead of

```
self.d['name'] = n
```

(But really, you shouldn't be inheriting from `dict` here. Also, please don't use `list` as an identifier, it's the name of a builtin.)

Comment: @larsmans--It appears iv misunderstood the effect of inheriting from `dict`. 2 questions: 1. What exactly does inheriting from `dict` do? and 2. When should one inherit from `dict`?

Comment: @codeninja: (1) inheriting from `dict` does nothing magical; it does the what inheritance always does. You get the methods and attributes of the superclass in your class. (2) You should inherit from `dict` when you're creating a custom dictionary class, like `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

you should save `self.d` instead of `self`:

```
  alist.append(self.d)
  listStr = repr(alist)
  f.write(listStr)
```

btw don't use *list* as the name of a variable, you are overwritting the keyword `list`

Comment: But even then there should be some gibberish in brackets becaus he uses repr([object, object ...]). And it seems he wants to do a manual pickle..., so self would be ok either. (Even if it's not quite there!)

Comment: @Don Question I played with it. Inside the method self has no contents (try `print self'). self is an empty dict. The dict is self.d

Comment: My bad, i oversaw his base-class inheriting from dict! I didn't say anything! ;-)

Comment: @Don Question, yes, right you can print dir(self), print repr(self), whatever. Obviously the object is there. What I meant was that, in this case,if you print self you get `{}`, an empty dictionary, because Person subclass bookEntry that itself subclass dict. As `dict().__repr__()` is `{}`,  and that dict has not been filled with data you get simply `{}` as the printed representation of the object. Sorry if my comment was ambiguous.

Comment: @Don Question X-comments -> Oh! It took to me 14 minutes to reply your previous (already deleted) comment !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the X.d dictionary is not the same as the dictionary "bookEntry" is inheriting from. Therefore repr(X) is not showing X.d

A solution might be to override repr in BookEntry:

e.g.

```
def __repr___(self):
  return repr(self.d)
```